# How to change language of the strings of an app(In Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, string, android-studio

I have around 6 java classes with its layouts, all of them have strings that I will like the user to change by pressing a button. Under my **RES** directory I have two directories, **values** and **values-en**, in each of these there is a **`strings.xml`** file, one in English and the other one in Spanish. The thing is, I don't know what to add to my java code in order to change all the strings of all the layouts.

Comment: i guess the normal values directory is english, so you have to define a spanish values directory

Answer (score 0):

That the great thing about using 'res/values' for storing dimensions, layouts and strings. It is all automatically handled for you.

> Android can select and load resources from different directories,
>   based on the current    device configuration and locale.

With your current set up, your app will always be in spanish unless the user's device language is English. So if a user from Germany downloads your app, it will be in spanish.

If you live in the US and your device language is English, it will search for strings the following way:

> ‘res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml’ if not found, than 
>   ‘res/values-en/strings.xml’ if not found, than 
>   ‘res/values/strings.xml’

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept it or upvote. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour